# How to describe parameters of passed anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, anonymous-function, jsdoc

I want to describe `curVal` with JSDoc?

I tried `@param` just before `arrays.every()` and inside anonymous callback, but it didn't help for `PhpStorm` to resolve methods.

```
/**
 * @param {Array} curVal
 */
arrays.every(function (curVal) {
    /**
     * @param {Array} curVal
     */     
    curVal.???
});
```

I need it for convinience, I just want to easily access in IDE's autocompletion `Array.prototype` methods on object `curVal`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how smart PhpStorm is ([the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/creating-jsdoc-comments.html) say it recognizes Closure Compiler [tags and type annotations](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Annotating-JavaScript-for-the-Closure-Compiler)), but I can think of two possible solutions.

First is to tell it directly the type of the function param:

```
arrays.every(/** @param {Array} curVal */ function (curVal) {
  // ...
});
```

Or (Closure Compiler inline style):

```
arrays.every(function (/** Array */ curVal) {
  // ...
});
```

Second, and this will only work if PhpStorm is smart enough to know how `Array.prototype.every`'s callback gets its arguments, is to make sure it knows `arrays` is an array of arrays:

```
/** @type {Array.<Array>} */
var arrays = getArrays();
```

Or:

```
var arrays = /** Array.<Array> */ getArrays();
```

Comment: This is great, I tried all of Your propositions and I first and second worked flawlessly. I need to double check because PhpStorm seems to have some sort of cache, and while I remove first type annotation IDE remembers that it was Array. Then I changed it to Object, then again with second option changed to Array. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think your best (and most legible) option is to give the function a name, e.g.

```
/**
 * @type {Number[]}
 */
var array = [ 1, 2, 3 ];

/**
 * @param {Number} curVal
 */
var fn = function (curVal) {
    // operate on curVal
};
array.forEach(fn);
```

I think you should (and perhaps must) specify the array type, as in my example, not not just `{Array}`, and I don't know what you mean by `arrays.every`, but I assume you meant to use `.forEach` from the Array object.

**[Edit]**

OK, now I understand, maybe something like this is what you want:

```
/**
 * @param {Array} curVal
 */
var fn = function (curVal) {
    curVal. // press Ctrl-Space here, and autocompletion will work
};
```

However, if you really want to use jsdoc with an anonymous function, something like this will work (and is closest to the code in your question):

```
var arrayOfArrays = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4]]
arrayOfArrays.every(/** @param {Array} curVal */function (curVal) {
    curVal. // press Ctrl-Space here, and autocompletion will work
});
```

(I use JetBrains' IntelliJ, not their PhpStorm IDE, but they share the same Javascript integration)